# Running ADUC as different user - wrong directory

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to powershell. 
In this code my coworkers are getting an error which I'm not getting. 
I've tried some different things (like adding the complete path to powershell) but I'm not able to fix it. 
Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

[image: Error my coworkers are getting.]

```
Function Button4_Click()
{
    $Filepathmmc = join-path -path  $env:SystemRoot -ChildPath System32\Mmc.exe
    $argumentlistdsa =  join-path -path  $env:SystemRoot -ChildPath System32\dsa.msc
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -ArgumentList (Get-Content "$($env:userprofile)\username.txt"),(Get-Content "$($env:userprofile)\encrypt.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "Start-Process -FilePath '$filepathmmc' -ArgumentList '$argumentlistdsa' -Verb RunAs"
}
```

I also tried using this as the Start-Process path:

```
$aducpath = (Join-Path $Env:SystemRoot -ChildPath "\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe")
```

[image: error]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

[Needs elevation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5IwU.png)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all the necessary files exist in the system root and user profile locations on their computers?

Comment: That was my first idea, so I double checked.

Comment: I've also tried to run it in 64bit and 32 bit.

Comment: Just noticed your screenshot is different from the code you supplied. Start-Process $aducpath whereas the code you supplied uses start-process powershell. What is the value of the $aducpath variable?

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding the complete path,
```
 $aducpath = (Join-Path $Env:SystemRoot -ChildPath "\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe")
```

Comment: What happens when you just use powershell or powershell.exe?

Comment: I added three screenshots.

Comment: Why are you running another powershell session instead of directly starting mmc.exe with credentials `Start-Process $Filepathmmc -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $argumentlistdsa`?

Comment: Because you need to elevate it, before you can runas. (Screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are still using join-path, have you tried using an absolute path for the sake of troubleshooting?

I also see that you're reading a password from a text file. I would advise you not to do that, and instead maybe have users log in themselves instead for elevation. If you replace `$Credential` in the invocation process with `(Get-Credential)` it will prompt your user for elevation. You can also use `$Credential = Get-Credential` to save it for the future.

I can't reproduce the error you're getting with just this code snippet. All of your Join-Paths are sane and seem to point to the expected place. When run as an unprivileged user, I get a UAC prompt rather than the invalid code. If there is actually a problem with where things are, might I suggest that you use something like this to search for what you need?

```
Function Button4_Click()
{
    $Filepathmmc = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $env:SystemRoot -Filter "Mmc.exe").FullName | Select-Object -First 1
    $argumentlistdsa =  (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $env:SystemRoot -Filter "dsa.mmc").FullName | Select-Object -First 1
    Start-Process powershell -Credential (Get-Credential) -ArgumentList "Start-Process -FilePath '$filepathmmc' -ArgumentList '$argumentlistdsa' -Verb RunAs"
}
```

It's not perfect, but it will always return *an* instance of mmc. You can add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the Get-ChildItem command to suppress the inevitable 'Accesss to the path X is denied' exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try that asap.  
I did try adding paths to everything to make sure. Like I said, it works for me but my coworkers are seeing the errors. Which is weird. They have the exact same setup like I have.
I'll keep your recommendations in mind for password-saving.